# What exactly happens when a create a variable in java of class type?

Tags: java, class, object

```
public class Point {
   ...
}

class Line{
    Point location;
    ...
}
```

So what does this location variable with type `Point`, exactly do? It doesn't give me an error so I know it's correct, but what is the purpose of it. When I do that, is it the same as doing:

```
Point location = new Point();
```

Or no? Can I access methods using my location variable I created? Why or why not?

Comment: Since `Point location;` is class field it is same as `Point location = null;`. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html -> Default Values